# ASP.NET Core Web API with Kerberos Ticket forwarding

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, kerberos, kdc

I am building **Web API** with **ASP.NET Core** hosted on **IIS** that will act as proxy integrating a few services.
I need to forward user credentials/identity to specific services managed by my API and to do so i want to enable ticket **forwarding** in **Kerberos**.

What steps i need to take to make it work?

First of all I need to setup my service as trusted in **KDC** and after that should it will received **forwardable** tickets instead of regular ones (*i need to specific services that my API can forwards tickets to*), am i right?

How do i then forward that ticket to other service using `HttpClient`? 
Does attaching received token to request will be enough?

Am i correct about listed by me steps and is there any thing more to do?

Thank you all for help.